# How to re-scale the each of the `faces` by without changing the arrangement using CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a `graph` using `css3` with multiple faces. according to the values, I would like to re-scale the faces without changing the arrangement of them ( alignment) I understand that, there is a way of algorithm to keep the angles and arrangement. but i don't have any idea about it.

any one who much-familiar with this kind of works, can help me please?

```js
$(function(){
  
  var faces = $('.face');
  
  $('button').on('click', function () {
    
    faces.each(function(i, el) {
      var value = Math.round(Math.random()* 100 );
      $('.percent').eq([i]).text(value);
     $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + (value/100) + ')');
      
    })
    
  })
  
})
```

```css
.container {
 width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}

.face div,
.face{
    position:absolute;
}

#triangle-f1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    top:30px;
}

.percent {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
}

.f1p{
    top: -10%;
    left: 0;
    color:#aaa02d;
}

.f2p{
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    color:green;
}

.f3p{
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    color:brown;
}

.yellow-f1 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 50px solid yellow;
 border-right: 50px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
}

.yellow-f2 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 50px solid #aaa02d;
 border-left: 50px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
}

#triangle-f2{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top:30px;
    left:8px;
}

.blue-f1 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 50px solid #1aa0a4;
 border-right: 50px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
}

.blue-f2 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 50px solid #1fc2c7;
 border-left: 50px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
}

#triangle-f3{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    top:26px;
    left:8px;
    transform: rotate(2deg);
}

.brown-f1 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 25px solid transparent;
 border-right: 24px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 20px solid #7b2235;
    right:0;
    top:30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.brown-f2 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 40px solid transparent;
 border-right: 40px solid #ae4259;
 border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    right:18px;
    top:32px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
    transform: rotate(-12deg);
      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <h1>Diagram <button>Change Values</button></h1>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="percent f1p">100%</div>
    <div id="triangle-f1" class="face">
        <div class="yellow-f1"></div>
        <div class="yellow-f2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="percent f2p">100%</div>
    <div id="triangle-f2" class="face">
        <div class="blue-f1"></div>
        <div class="blue-f2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="percent f3p">100%</div>
    <div id="triangle-f3" class="face">
        <div class="brown-f1"></div>
       <div class="brown-f2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when you click on change value button you will find the issue. please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Store initial transform in some place and apply it before scaling:

```js
$(function(){
  
  var faces = $('.face');
  
  $('button').on('click', function () {
    
    faces.each(function(i, el) {
      var value = Math.round(Math.random()* 100 );
      $('.percent').eq([i]).text(value);
      var initialTransform = $(this).data('transform');
     $(this).css('transform', initialTransform+ ' scale(' + (value/100) + ')');
      
    })
    
  })
  
})
```

```css
.container {
 width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}

.face div,
.face{
    position:absolute;
}

#triangle-f1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg)  ;
    top:30px;
}

.percent {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
}

.f1p{
    top: -10%;
    left: 0;
    color:#aaa02d;
}

.f2p{
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    color:green;
}

.f3p{
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    color:brown;
}

.yellow-f1 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 50px solid yellow;
 border-right: 50px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
}

.yellow-f2 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 50px solid #aaa02d;
 border-left: 50px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
}

#triangle-f2{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top:30px;
    left:8px;
}

.blue-f1 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 50px solid #1aa0a4;
 border-right: 50px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
}

.blue-f2 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 50px solid #1fc2c7;
 border-left: 50px solid transparent;
     -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg);
}

#triangle-f3{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    top:26px;
    left:8px;
    transform: rotate(2deg);
}

.brown-f1 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 25px solid transparent;
 border-right: 24px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 20px solid #7b2235;
    right:0;
    top:30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.brown-f2 {
    width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 40px solid transparent;
 border-right: 40px solid #ae4259;
 border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    right:18px;
    top:32px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-12deg);
    transform: rotate(-12deg);
      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <h1>Diagram <button>Change Values</button></h1>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="percent f1p">100%</div>
    <div id="triangle-f1" class="face" data-transform="rotate(20deg)">
        <div class="yellow-f1"></div>
        <div class="yellow-f2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="percent f2p">100%</div>
    <div id="triangle-f2" class="face" data-transform="rotate(90deg)">
        <div class="blue-f1"></div>
        <div class="blue-f2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="percent f3p">100%</div>
    <div id="triangle-f3" class="face"  data-transform="rotate(2deg)">
        <div class="brown-f1"></div>
       <div class="brown-f2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On random values, the arrangement of the shapes are missing.

Comment: could you give some example values when it is happening?